# Several radio buttons selected at same time

Tags: c#, radio-button, dynamic-programming

I have several dynamically created rows that have radio buttons in them.  Every time I click on one radio button it sets all the other radio buttons to false.  Is there a way so only one radio button becomes false and not the rest of the radio buttons?

Comment: Is this WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET? ..?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use check boxes instead or radio buttons.

Comment: It sounds like you want each row to have its own button group, so that you can have 1 radio selected per row, correct? You need the `name` attribute to be different in each row. FE, row 1 all of the radio buttons have `name="myRadio_1"`, while in row 2 all of the radio buttons have `name="myRadio_2"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to group your radio buttons by **name**

Example:

```
<input type='radio' name="group1" /> 
<input type='radio' name="group1" /> 
<input type='radio' name="group1" />

<input type='radio' name="group2" /> 
<input type='radio' name="group2" /> 
<input type='radio' name="group2" />
```

If you click a radio button in group2 it shouldn't affect group1.

Answer (score 2):

Do you own the code generating the dynamically created rows?  The functionality you're aiming for is indicative of check boxes rather than radio buttons.